# How Can SUM data in Multi columns from multi tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-columns, union

I have 4 Tables :

1- Suppliers

| ID_A | Supplier_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Xiaomi |
| 3 | Nokia |
| 4 | Oppo |

2- Start Balance

| ID_B | Start Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 |
| 3 | 1000 |
| 4 | Null |

3- Invoices

| ID_C | Invoice_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 800 |
| 3 | 250 |
| 3 | 400 |
| 4 | Null |

4- Returns

| ID_D | Return_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | Null |
| 4 | Null |

arithmetic method for the results to show data :

Start Balance + Invoices - Returns = End Balance

i tried to use UNION with JOINS in mysql :

```
 SELECT   null  , Supplier_name , ID_A  , SUM(Invoice_value) , null ,  null FROM Suppliers          
             inner  JOIN  Invoices 
             ON ID_A = ID_C 
group by ID_A  
        
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT   null  , Supplier_name , ID_A  , null , SUM(Return_value),  null  FROM Suppliers          
             left  JOIN  Returns 
             ON ID_A = ID_D
             
group by ID_A 



UNION ALL

  SELECT   Start Balance ,  Supplier_name, ID_A   , null  , null   ,( Start Balance + ifnull(SUM(Invoice_value),0) - ifnull(SUM(Return_value),0) )  FROM Suppliers         
          left  JOIN   Start Balance 
           ON ID_A = ID_B
           left  JOIN  Invoices 
           ON ID_A = ID_C 
           left  JOIN  Returns 
           ON ID_A = ID_D 
          
           group by ID_A
```

I EXPECT THIS RESULT TO BE :

| Start Balance | Supplier_name | ID_A | Invoice_value | Return_value | End_Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Apple | 1 | 700 | 100 | 1600 |
| 1000 | Xiaomi | 2 | 800 | 75 | 1725 |
| 1000 | Nokia | 3 | 650 | null | 1650 |
| null | Oppo | 4 | null | null | null |

but it didnt work well it show the results in differant rows and the calculate of end balance is wrong
please what is the wright code to show this result

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the sums in subquery and join them together

```
  SELECT   `Start Balance`,
      Supplier_name
    , ID_A   , `Invoice_value`
    , `Return_value`   ,
    `Start Balance` + IFNULL(Invoice_value,0) - ifnull(Return_value,0)  total  
   FROM Suppliers         
          left  JOIN   Start_Balance 
           ON ID_A = ID_B
           left  JOIN  
    ( SELECT `ID_C`, SUM(`Invoice_value`) `Invoice_value` FROM Invoices GROUP By ID_C)  i
           ON ID_A = ID_C 
           left  JOIN  
    ( SELECT `ID_D`, SUM(`Return_value`) `Return_value` FROM Returns GROUP BY `ID_D`) r
           ON ID_A = ID_D
```

| Start Balance | Supplier_name | ID_A | Invoice_value | Return_value | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Apple | 1 | 700 | 100 | 1600 |
| 1000 | Xiaomi | 2 | 800 | 75 | 1725 |
| 1000 | Nokia | 3 | 650 | *null* | 1650 |
| *null* | Oppo | 4 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zHGCGJC5)

Comment: Why the outer layer of aggregation?

Comment: yes i didn't remove the GROUP By from the query before

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution(Mysql) with CTE...

```
with jp as
 (
     select sb.`Start Balance`,sp.Supplier_name,sp.ID_A,sum(iv.Invoice_value) ivvle
     from Start_Balance sb
     join Suppliers sp on sp.ID_A = sb.ID_B
     join Invoices iv on  iv.ID_C = sb.ID_B
     group by 1,2,3
 ) 
     select jp.`Start Balance`,jp.Supplier_name,jp.ID_A,jp.ivvle Invoice_Valuee ,
     sum(Return_value) Return_Valuee,
     jp.`Start Balance`+jp.ivvle-ifnull(sum(Return_value),0) End_Balances
     from Returns rt 
     left join jp on rt.ID_D = jp.ID_A
     group by 1,2,3,4
```

[image: Result]

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SBoDeOyV)